# Как настроить размер шрифта под размер кнопки в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я пишу калькулятор на ткинтере и столкнулся с проблемой. Кнопки я выравниваю одинаково с помощью weight=1 в grid_rowconfigure и grid_columnnfigure. Но при увеличении окна кнопка увеличивается, а текст в ней нет, и это выглядит некрасиво. Помогите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: label.config(font=("Algerian", 50))

Comment: или план б. чтобы размер окна никто не менял root.resizable(0, 0)

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 варианта

1. Брать Scale из OS, 100%, 150%, 200% (настраивается самой ОС)
2. Взять height Desktop, разделить на N и получить размер фонта.

Обычно беру второй, потому что по факту он оказывается более адекватный.

Comment: Не очень понял оба способа. Что такое height Desktop и N?